# How to use npm python-shell in react js app?

Tags: python, reactjs

I am trying to run and display some simple python code and was hoping I could use the [python-shell package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell). Is it possible to run the package with react js?

I have a code sandbox below. Is there a way to run the simple "x=1+1;print(x)" script when the button is clicked?

CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/little-meadow-wlni3

Here is the Code.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { PythonShell } from "python-shell";

export default class Code extends Component {
  render() {
    function runPython() {
      PythonShell.runString("x=1+1;print(x)", null, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("finished");
      });
    }
    return (
      <>
        <div className="output">code goes here</div>
        <button type="button" onClick={runPython}>
          Run
        </button>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: PythonShell is typically used on the back end to run python from a nodejs app. React is  a front end framework (and a web browser only runs javascript) and therefore I doubt this is easily possible. Are you building your React app for the web or native?

Comment: thanks, yeah was hoping there was a way to maybe process it somehow and send over the the web app

Answer (score 0):

ended up creating an express.js backend api and ran it through there to process the python and then sent the output to the react client side.